# How to use variable inside variable in angular template?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am new to angular , can someone tell me if I can use variable inside variable in angular.
Explaination:

I am creating one dropdown input component where it will make api call to get data.
There is an `@Input() selector:string = ""` which will tell what to select from data

Inside template it will run `*ngFor` loop, then inside html I want to display as kind of like that:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item.id">
        {{ item.{{selector}} }}
 </option>
```

In other module it will be used as:

1. In one module `<app-input [selector]="'name'"></app-input>`
2. Another one.  `<app-input [selector]="'id'"></app-input>`

How Can I use `selector` inside this any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
{{ item[selector] }}
```

use the bracket syntax for accessing a property with a variable key.